# Spring boot lazy loaded entity not loading all properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, mysql-8.0

I have a `Spring Boot 2.1.13` (Java 8) project with `MySQL 8.0.21` and `mysql-connector-java version: 8.0.22` with the following classes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"type", "location", "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {
    private UserType userType;
    private Location location;
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "usertypeid")
    public UserType getUserType() {
        return this.userType;
    }

    public void setUserType(UserType userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "locationid", nullable = false)
    public Location getLocation() {
        return this.location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "usertype")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class UserType implements java.io.Serializable {
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
public class Location implements java.io.Serializable {
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

---

I fetch the user record using the following code

```
User user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElse(null);
```

Now when I try to fetch the UserType object from my user object, I don't get any values, except the **ID**. For example, when I run the following command, it gives me a `null` value

```
user.getUserType().getName()
```

However, when I run the following code, I get the expected not null value.

```
user.getLocation().getName()
```

Both `userType` and `location` are lazy-loaded, however, the values of only `location` are available in the code.

---

- I have checked the values in DB tables. They are not `null` for both user type and location.
- I have checked the values in the debugger as well. The `Location` object seems to be a proxy, however, the `UserType` not a hibernate proxy object. I am not sure if this is an issue.

Comment: UserType is enum?

Comment: No. It is a table in DB. I have added the class for that as well

Comment: @greenPadawan Try to enable hibernate sql logs: `hibernate.show_sql`, `hibernate.format_sql`, `hibernate.use_sql_comments` and see what queries are actually generated.

Comment: I tried to check the hibernate logs. No query is executed when I `user.getUserType().getName()`

Comment: Please add the queries that are executed to your question. Maybe the association is eager loaded and the other attributes are simply null? Also, try clearing your persistence context by using `entityManager.clear` before running that query to see if this solves your issue. Maybe your persistence context contains a wrong version of that entity?